# How to determine time complexity of below code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
public void test(int n)
{
   for(i=1;i<=n;i=i*2)
  {
     for(j=1;j<n;j=j+(j*i))
      {
         // some code
      }
  }
}
```

Above code has two loop. The outer loop which execute log(n) times. How can we calculate the number of times inner loop will execute?
What will be time complexity of above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop takes log_{i+1}(n) time (log base i+1 of n). Assuming n is a power of 2, and using the change of base formula, to convert to base 2: log_{i+1)(n) = lg(n)/lg(i+1), that means the "some code" will be executed this many times: lg(n)/lg(2) + lg(n)/lg(3) + lg(n)/lg(5) + ... + lg(n)/lg(n+1).

Now, 1/lg(2) + 1/lg(3) + ... + 1/lg(n+1) <= 1 + 1/lg(2) + 1/lg(4) + ...1/lg(n) = 1 + 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/lg(n) ~= (1 + log(lg(n))).

Similarly, 1/lg(2) + 1/lg(3) + ... + 1/lg(n+1) >= 1/lg(4) + 1/lg(8) + ... + 1/lg(2n) ~= (log(lg(2n)) - 1). (Using an approximation to the harmonic numbers: H(n) ~= log(n)).

Thus it seems that the complexity is log(n)log(log(n)).

This is a pretty sketchy proof, but hopefully will point you in the right direction.

Comment: The inner loop has complexity log_{i+1}(n). I don't multiply the inner time complexity by the other time complexity because that's not a valid way of computing complexities (although it works in common polynomial cases). I compute the inner runtime, and sum it up over the values the outer loop takes on. It's a rather difficult example to be honest, and if you don't understand the working I'm not sure I can help further.

Comment: Note, it's quite possible I've made a mistake in the working.